# What is the role of the pattern object in this implementation?

Tags: equation-solving, pattern-matching, fitting

In the documentation I found a nice idiom which allows me to do model fitting with interpolating functions. I think this kind of thing is amazing and a credit to the utility of an environment like Mathematica. It goes like this:

```
model[a_?NumberQ, b_?NumberQ, c_?NumberQ] :=  
Module[{y, x}, 
First[y /. 
NDSolve[{y''[x] + a y[x] == 0, y[0] == b, y'[0] == c}, 
y, {x, 0, 10}]]]

nlm = NonlinearModelFit[data, model[a, b, c][x], {a, b, c}, x]
```

I think I understand how this works but my question is this: what is the significance of the pattern object ?NumberQ when model is first defined? For example my initial implementation of this was as follows:

```
model[a_ ,t_] :=  
Module[{y, x}, 
First[y /. 
NDSolve[{a(y'[x] t + y[x] == vtest, y[0] == 0}, 
y, {x, 0, end}]
]]
```

This is a just a different diff eq where vtest and end are given values ahead of time. But if I run this through the NonlinearModelFit without the ?NumberQ pattern on the initial model definition I get an NDSolve error saying that it encountered a non-numerical derivative at x$16212==0. I know how to avoid this I just don't understand why it doesn't work. Any help understanding what this error message indicates and what the role of the pattern object is would be much appreciated.

Comment: I understand the basic idea of pattern matching. My question has more to do with what NonlinearModelFit is doing to cause "model" to be evaluated with non-numerical arguments and why this results in the error it does.

Comment: `NonlinearModelFit` does not have any `Hold*` attributes, so your code evaluates `model[a, b, c]` with symbolic arguments before `NonlinearModelFit` "sees" it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually since version 9 there is `ParametericNDSolve` and `NDSolveValue` which both make the mentioned idiom even more attractive and doesn't even need the pattern matching you are struggling with:

```
model = Module[{x, y, a, t}, 
  ParametricNDSolveValue[
    {a*(y'[x] t - y[x]) == 7, y[0] == 0}, y, {x, 0, 1}, {a, t}
  ]
]

data = {#, model[0.5, 0.6][#] + RandomReal[0.00025]} & /@ Range[0, 1, 0.025];

fit = Module[{a,t},NonlinearModelFit[data, model[a, t][x], {a, t}, x]]

fit@"BestFitParameters"
Show[ListPlot[data], Plot[fit[x], {x, 0, 1}]]
```

Answer (score 2):

The function checks if the input is a number (NumberQ), otherwise it prints out an error.

The function is only defined if the input is a number.

Please check this alternate example:

```
f[x_?OddQ] := "Here the function is defined for an odd number";
f[3]
```

But the function it is not defined for an even number:

```
f[2]
```

Comment: Why does the NonlinearModelFit seem to be running the function on non-numbers though?

Comment: https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/PuttingConstraintsOnPatterns.html,  The definition applies only when  the variable has a numerical argument.

Comment: I think I understand pattern matching. I'm just not sure I understand why the kernel would ever attempt to evaluate the expression with non-numerical arguments int the model[a_,t_] expression and why this results in the error that I mention.

Comment: Quit the Kernel and try again

Comment: Fresh kernel didn't help

Comment: @abrentonc: Mathematica is at its core a symbolic system, so it will evaluate a function for non-numeric arguments, e.g. `f[x_]:=x^3;y=.;f[y]`. If you call something like NDSolve which only handle those parameters as numeric input, then you have to restrict the function pattern to numeric parameters.